# Patron maestro detalle android, JSOn mostrar imagen

Tags: android, json

Tengo una imagen guardada en la base de datos, donde accedo a ella tomando la ruta de la imagen.. Y con el método cargarimagenwebservice la muestro:

```
private void cargarImagenWebService(String rutaimagen , final UsuariosHolder holder) {
            String ip = context.getString(R.string.ip);
            String url = ip + "/DBRemota/"+ rutaimagen;
            url = url.replace(" " , "%20");

        ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                holder.imagen.setImageBitmap(response);
            }
        }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error al cargar la imagen..." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
       // request.add(imageRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(context).addToRequestQueue(imageRequest);
    }
```

Con este método lo que hago es mostrarla en el recyclerView, pero cuando aplico el patrón maestro detalle como le paso la imagen??

En el activity del recyclet, implemente un metodo onclick y paso por parametro el objeto que se selecciono:

```
negocio Negocio = listanegocio.get(recyclernegocio.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Listanegocio.this, Listanegociodetalle.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("negocio",Negocio);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Y en el activity detalle, lo recibo y muestro:

```
Bundle objeto = getIntent().getExtras();
        negocio Negocio = null;



        if (objeto!=null){
            Negocio = (negocio) objeto.getSerializable("negocio");
            txnombre.setText(Negocio.getNombre());
            txtdes.setText(Negocio.getDescripcion());
            txthorario.setText(Negocio.getHorario());
            txtdireccion.setText(Negocio.getHorario());
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(Negocio.getRutaimagen()));

        }
```

Pero me larga error el setImageResource.. Si alguien me puede dar una mano se agradece...

Comment: @Nicethunder Si, disculpa.. pero ninguno se pudo resolver

Comment: Ya veo, entonces tu problema quedo en lo ultimo que te respondió @armen ?

Comment: @Nicethunder Si, lo que me planteo él no es legible

Comment: @Nicethunder Yo lo que necesito es como puedo ejecutar el método CargarWebServiceimagen en el activity detalle.

Comment: ya, entonces lo mejor seria continuar estas revisiones en la primera pregunta que hiciste ya que esta pregunta plantea el mismo problema te parece bien ?

Comment: @Nicethunder (y)